# Is there a way to get ASCII characters in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii

Python's built-in functions `ord` and `chr` return UNICODE characters, which are based on 16-bit numbers, and numbers respectively. Is there a way to get extended ASCII characters (0-255), which are based on 8-bit unsigned numbers, without defining a dictionary to do so?

I can use Unicode characters, but its control characters are not as same as ASCII (specifically 10, 13, 26, and 255). These four numbers are the main reason I can't use Unicode because they are important to my code.

10: Line Feed

13: Carriage Return

26: Substitute

255: nbsp

Comment: maybe `string.ascii_letters` might be what you are looking for?

Comment: Unicode codepoints from 0-127 are exactly the same as the ASCII characters, no mapping needed.

Comment: Are you sure they're the same? Are Unicode control character the same with ASCII control characters? I need extended ASCII characters, so those 8 bits are unsigned, and from 0-255.

Comment: @Enigmacy: There are about a thousand different extensions. For instance, some extensions have the euro sign €, but most don't. The first 256 characters of Unicode are specifically the ISO 8859-1 "Latin-1" extension to ASCII.

Comment: @MSalters For me the most important part is the control characters, specifically 10, 13, 26, and 255. Are Unicodes' control characters as same as ASCII?

Comment: @Enigmacy: there is no such thing as "extended ASCII". Or to be a little bit more precise: there are many, many 8-bit encodings based on ASCII that are all collectively sometimes referred to as "extended ASCII". But they are "extended ASCII" in much the same sense as Unicode it self is "extended ASCII". Please forget that this term exists, because it leads to exactly the kind of confusion that you have in this question. If you need "extended ASCII" then talk about the *specific* encoding(s) that you care about, but don't talk about ASCII (because it is only ever 0-127).

Comment: @Enigmacy: 10,13 and 26 are indeed in ASCII, every ASCII extension, and Unicode. But 255 is not a control character in most ASCII extensions, in particular not in ISO-8859-1. where it is `ÿ`. Therefore, U+00FF in Unicode is also `ÿ`

Comment: And regarding "are the first 128 Unicode codepoints exactly ASCII?": [yes, they are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Unicode). Very intentionally.

Comment: Python's strings are sequences of characters, not sequences of numbers. If you want the numbers representing the characters, only then does it matter whether you're decoding to Unicode or some extended ASCII or anything else. If your string is `s` then you can do `s.encode('ascii')` to get a `bytes` object which represents a sequence of integers in the range 0-255, corresponding to the ASCII values of the characters in your string.

Comment: Last but not least: I know of no 8-bit encoding where 255 is a control character (which obviously doesn't mean that there is no such encoding). In most encodings I know it's a normal (though usually rarely used) character and in some it's undefined. Most "extended ASCII" encodings tend to not define additional control characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python3 has the `bytes` type, which has a `decode` method to convert each byte to the corresponding Unicode character. But since there are about a thousand difference byte-oriented character sets, you'll have to tell `decode` which one you're using.

The Python 3 default is `'utf-8'`, but the comment "255 is a control code" tells me that you're not using UTF-8. Neither I nor Python have a crystal ball, so you'll need to figure out the name of the character set you're using.

[edit]
The "nbsp" probably means Non-Breaking Space, U+00A0. If that's encoded as 255, you're probably dealing with some flavor of [DOS code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#DOS_code_pages). `.decode('cp850')` may work, but as I said there are thousands of extensions, and guessing the wrong name will give weird Unicode output.